# Concatenate while yielding

Tags: python, generator, yield

How can I concatenate two items when yielding from a function in python?

The base case:

```
import itertools

def test():
    for number in range(0,10):
        yield number

list(test()) # [0...9]
```

What if I want to yield both the `number` and its square `number**2`

```
import itertools

def test():
    for number in range(0,10):
        yield itertools.chain.from_iterable([
            number,number*2
        ])

list(test()) 

# [0,0,1,1,2,4,3,9,...] pretended
# <itertools.chain at 0x135decfd0> ... what I got
```

However doing `itertools.chain.from_iterable([generator1, generator2])` from the outside gives the expected result.

```
def first_list():
    for number in range(0,5):
        yield number

def second_list():
    for number in range(5,10):
        yield number

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([first_list(), second_list()]))
```

Comment: Why not simply: `yield number <newline> yield number**2`?

Comment: You don't want to concatenate, you want a double yield ... that's a difference.

Comment: from the outside they come out concatenated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way is:

```
def test():
    for number in range(0,10):
        yield number 
        yield number**2
```

Answer (score 11):

Python 3.3 also introduced the `yield from` (see also [PEP-380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)) syntax which allows you to do something like this:

```
>>> def test():
...   for number in range(10):
...     yield from (number, number**2)
...
>>> list(test())
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16, 5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49, 8, 64, 9, 81]
```